# Is there any way to restore a Medium Draft?

Tags: medium

I wrote a somewhat lengthy draft in Medium, and today, when I opened it up to finish writing it, about the last half was gone. :( I probably should have made sure that it had finished saving, but am I right to have assumed that autosave would have worked, at least to save more than it did, considering that I spent at least 15 minutes on the last half.

Will I have to rewrite this, or is there some revision control functionality?

I don't mind redoing it, but I'm new to Medium and want to figure these things out as a n00b.

Comment: I am very sorry to say this, but what you are asking for is clearly not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Send an email to Medium. I've read that they keep your content for 14 days.

https://medium.com/@17/how-to-recover-deleted-medium-articles-6386356ccb7b